# Want to store password type in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password name" id="box2">
var pass=document.getElementById('box2').value;

xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("formchek").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
 } }; 
 xhttp.open("POST", "chek.php?msg="+pass, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

here when i am using input type="password" i dont get the value of password stored in text box of id box2 ussing the above code but using input type="text" gives me the value.So i wanna how to get the value using input type="password".

Comment: Don't shout. We can hear you.

Comment: `.value` works in exactly the same way on text and password inputs.

Comment: Maybe it does not work because your code is immediately after your input in this example? The user couldn't fill anything in. Try `onchange`, or `onsubmit`...

Comment: You can set the value just like in any other textbox, but by default, a password box's value would be set to an empty string on a refresh (for security reasons), unless your code handles that and stores something in it via a set to its value property or via server side code that injects into the value property.

Comment: You're not escaping `pass` here, so if it contains values incompatible with the URI encoding it'll wreck everything. A password of `this%20` is going to fail big-time. The [jQuery `ajax()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) handles this all for you properly.

Comment: can u give a code plzzz

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code to not store the value of password input, instead store the password input element's reference so that you can use at time of xhr request

```js
//  instead of  var pass=document.getElementById('box2').value;
var pass=document.getElementById('box2');

xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("formchek").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
 } }; 

 // instead of just pass, use pass.value
 xhttp.open("POST", "chek.php?msg="+ pass.value, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="Password name" id="box2">
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you refresh your browser, any password inputs' values are set to empty strings (for security reasons).

If you wish to retain that property, then you either need to do so by explicitly setting the value on the input itself...

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password name" id="box2" value="something">
```

The value of something would normally come from a bit server side scripting e.g.

```
<!-- using Classic ASP here, purely for example purposes -->
<input type="password" placeholder="Password name" id="box2" value="<%=user.getPassword()>">
```

Or via Javascript...

```
document.getElementById('box2').value = 'something';
```

If you're passing the password back in to the page via the querystring (not a good idea!), then you'll have to access the password from there and set it via Javascript, as above.